# Разделение бэкенд-архитектуры на сервер реального времени и сервер бизнес логики

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, redis, express

Я создаю приложение для заказа и доставке продуктов из супермаркетов. После осуществления заказа и его обработки магазином, необходимо чтобы этот заказ забрал ближайший водитель. При этом заказчик должен в реальном времени видеть статус его заказа и локацию водителя.

Планирую разделить логику на сервер реального времени (РТС) и сервер бизнес логики. (БЛС)

- В задачи БЛС будет входить: авторизация пользователей и водителей (JWT токены), получение и обработка заказов, платежная система.
- РТС будет использоваться для мониторинга локаций всех водителей и создания соединения на веб сокетах. Водитель должен будет постоянно слать свою локацию с GPS, чтобы быть онлайн

Общение РТС -БЛС будет происходить с помощью Redis pub/sub. При этом часть данных о заказе и информация о водителе будет копироваться из MongoDB и храниться в Redis. Таким образом информация будет общедоступной для всех серверов РТС (если я буду расширять горизонтально архитектуру). Поиск ближайшего водителя к заказу изначально планировался через MongoDB Geosearch, но тогда бы пришлось постоянно записывать в MongoDB локации водителей - а это очень много обращений к БД. Поэтому я хочу реализовать поиск ближайших сущностей через Redis.

- БЛС использует Node.js+Express+Mongo
- РТС использует Socket.io

  ## Вопрос:

  1. Правильно ли я спроэктировал архитектуру приложения?
  2. Как реализовать авторизацию драйверов на РТС, если вся логика получения и создания токенов на БЛС.
  3. Токены доступа могут устареть со временем, но при этом водитель все еще может быть связан с РТС сервером, нужно ли мне обрывать соединение и просить водителя снова авторизоваться на БЛС и прислать мне новый токен?
  4. Какой гео поиск будет быстрее, с помощью MongoDB или Redis?

Comment: 1. архитектуру приложения не выбирают, а проектируют 2. все правильно, авторизация у вас через БЛС, далее вы можете хранить ключ(токен)-значение(объект юзера) в редисе или мемкеше (советую мемкеш, по перформансу лучше, редис однопоточный), а через РТС слать хедер с токеном (например, в socket.io есть параметр `extraHeaders`)  3. не нужно, достаточно сделать рефреш токена 4. перефразируйте вопрос

Comment: @overthesanity мой ресерч по редису показал, что в ней нет возможности создавать отдельные коллекции (по аналогии с монго) для разных сущностей (отдельно токен - драйвер и отедльно orderId - driverId ), есть поддержка только заранее установленного числа БД. Не должно ли это стать преградой в выборе редис в качестве хранилища позиции водителей на РТС и использовании для этих целей монго?

Comment: на первый вопрос (который вы перефразировали) вам здесь никто не ответит, к тому же то, что вы описали, например общение ртс-блс будет происходить через редис - это не проектирование, а решение определенной проблемы. По поводу геопоиска если у вас здесь много отношений (relations) между таблицами - mongodb для такого не очень подходит (как и редис конечно), используйте какую-то реляционную БД, тот же postgresql